# How to: set extension pint for an "extend" relationship between 2 usecases in Enterprise Architect?

Tags: uml, use-case, enterprise-architect

How to set extension pint for an "extend" relationship between 2 usecases in Enterprise Architect?

Answer (score 1):

Oh,
I found it.
By right-clicking on a usecase in usecase diagram, then selecting advanced, there is an item called "Edit Extension points"